# Compare list contents in excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

So here's my situation:  I am creating a sheet where I have 9 groupings of 3 lists where the items chosen are all contained in lists made via data validation.  What I need to do is add a score to each of these groups of 3, where if the 3 choices made from the data validation list are unique from the choices made in previous groupings of 3 (Note that the groupings of 3 will never be the same choices, they will always be unique to each other).

Basically, say in group 1 you have blue, green, and purple - giving the value of 1 as the choices are unique.  In group 2 you have orange, yellow, and pink - giving it a value of 1 also as the choices are unique.  So on and so forth, however, say in group 9 you have magenta, red, and purple - this group will score 0 as it is not completely unique (purple was chosen in group 1).  Note that choices are made at different times, and scored at these separate intervals - so where group 2 only compares to group 1, group 3 compares to both group 1 & 2, and so on.

I tried a formula similar to:

```
=IF(NOT(B1:B3=A1:A3),1,0)
```

However, the cell displayed a score of `#VALUE!` instead of the 1 or 0.  I'm wondering if I need to do each cell individually, so if the contents of cell B1 is not equal to the contents in A1, A2, or A3 then check the contents of cell B2 and if they are not equal to the contents of cells A1, A2, or A3 then check the contents of cell B3 and if they are not equal to the contents of A1:A3 then the value of that list is 1.  If I do have to do this individually, any ideas how I would word the formula?  Would it be something like:

```
=IF(NOT(A1:A3=B1,NOT(A1:A3=B2,NOT(A1:A3=B3),1,0)))
```

Is it even possible to do this in excel?

I am using the most current version of excel (office 365) with windows 10.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: My first troubleshooting action would be to use defined (named) ranges and try it again. YMMV.

Comment: I'm not sure I phrased things correctly, or I do not understand what you mean by using defined ranges.  The groups are all randomly picked by different individuals, where they cannot see the previous groups list.  Excel would have to check the cells to see if the contents matched, then assign a score to the group based on if it's contents are unique or not.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step (to support any level of future readers)

Use function `COUNTIF()` to know if a range holds a value. IOW, to check if the value in `B1` occurs in range `A1:A3`, you can write

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A3,B1)
```

which you can turn to a boolean result by comparing with 0 (meaning `B1` is not in `A1:A3`)

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A3,B1)=0
```

But you need to also check that `B2` and `B3` do not occur in `A1:A3`. You can use the `AND()` function for that:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A1:A3,B1)=0,COUNTIF(A1:A3,B2)=0,COUNTIF(A1:A3,B3)=0)
```

which will return True if none of `B1`, `B2` and `B3` occurs in `A1:A3`. To enable us to copy that function across a row and adjust the range that will be checked we change the reference to the first cell into a fixed column reference, `A1:A3` -> `$A1:A3`. When we copy the formula to the right, the range will grow to `$A1:B3`, `$A1:C3` and so on to finally `$A1:I3` for the nineth column

The above formula returns a boolean result, `True` or `False`. You indicated that you need 1 or 0, which is easily done with addition of an `IF()` function around the previous formula.

We can now write the formula to cell `B4` as

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A1:A3,B1)=0,COUNTIF($A1:A3,B2)=0,COUNTIF($A1:A3,B3)=0),1,0)
```

then copy to cells `C4:I4`

Since by your definition, each group of 3 are unique to eachother, no formula is needed in `A4`, you can simply set it to 1.

**Update**

Note! Empty cells in a range like `C1:C3` result in 1. You did not specify it, but you may want a group with missing values to return 0 instead. You can do that by adding a fourth term to the `AND()` function: `COUNTBLANK((B1:B3)=0`. The entry in `B4` would then be

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A1:A3,B1)=0,COUNTIF($A1:A3,B2)=0,COUNTIF($A1:A3,B3)=0,COUNTBLANK(B1:B3)=0),1,0)
```

before copying to cells `C4:I4`